# Woocommerce Default sorting not working when set custom ordering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress+woocommerce and getting issue in sorting. By default i have set option "Custom Ordering+Name" in woocommerce settings. But my other filters like sort by price, Popularity are not working. I have tried to use this hook and it's working but it shows by default all products with highest to low price. I want to set "Custom ordering" when page will load first time and then if user will choose other option like price, popularity then ordering should work according to selected filters.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = 'desc'; 
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Default ordering can be set in the menu WooCommerce > Settings > Products

Comment: Yes i have set in the menu WooCommerce > Settings > Products. It's working for custom ordering which is first option. But for other option not working like price, popularity when we choose these from drop down on front end

Comment: Works fine for me in WooCommerce 3.3.3.  Only thing it doesn't do is change the combobox filter to the "high to low" selection when I default it to that type with the filter "woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args"

Answer (score 3):

You can you use this code in your functions.php file to set the combobox filter to **Sort by price: high to low**.  I don't know why your filters are not working, they work fine for me in WooCommerce 3.3.3.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'modify_woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby');

function modify_woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    if( empty( $orderby ) ) {
        return 'price-desc';
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

Comment: Please also look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294610/how-to-change-the-woocommerce-search-result-orderby-into-price-low-to-high/49295676#49295676

Comment: I have checked one more thing. This is not coming "orderby=popularity" in query string when i choose price or popularity from sort drop down. It seems it redirects to the same page and nothing happen.

Comment: @testingexpert popularity is based on "total_sales", if you haven't sold anything then the filter won't do anything.