# How to change the Woocommerce search result orderby into price low to high

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

On my website i updated the woocommerce into 3.3.3 then the search result page showing products search results start with the “relevance” orderby by default. But woocommerce have bug i reported that [bug](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19362) and they solved by editing one core file. The Bug is relevance is not showing on the search page containing dropdown not showing “relevance” orderby by default.

Now i want to change the default “relevance” orderby into price low to high i added this code in function.php.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    if ('is_search' ) {

    $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = 'asc'; 
    return $args;
   }
}
```

This code is working for me but the search page containing dropdown field value still showing relevance i want to change that one also into price low to high.Please see attached screenshot. How i do that ?? could you please someone help me!!

[image]

Comment: I guess, you have to edit it in the front-end to make it work using `Ajax`. See the main `HTML` file.

Comment: Did you replace the files mentioned in the pull request?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'jwc_custom_product_query' );
function jwc_custom_product_query( $query ) {

    if( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if( ! isset( $query->query['s'] ) )
        return;

    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'price' );

    return $query; 
}
```

Comment: Yes i added that code in function.php i need to change the orderby dropdown also.

Comment: In latest version of WooCommerce, changing dropdown, go to WP Admin->Appearance->Customizing ->WooCommerce->Product Catalog->Default product sorting to "Sort by price(asc)"

Comment: This seems unnecessary as there's a default setting for this in WooCommerce itself. @developerme if even this doesn't work, then the issue may be connected to something else. Try disabling all other plugins and using default theme as you did when you initially created that bug report.